# How to implement Firebase Invites in my Android application?

Tags: firebase, firebase-invites

I want to implement the Firebase Invite Feature, where a user can send a link which is unique to his/her friends and whenever the other receiver installs the app using this link my application recognize it and act accordingly.

Now I have searched quite a while about Firebase invite and I came to know that you can send the link only via email and android messages. However, I want the user to send via any other social networking app.

What approach should be followed while implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Invites is a UI layer to send dynamic links to other users through email. If you want to send the links with another service, you can create them directly using [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/).